# Use value from Long calculated Select to Next statements?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query (in sp) which takes long time to Execute :

e.g.

```
Select name, age ,token1 from Mytable where id=2 //long calc....

//later on the same sp...

select anotherCalc from Table2 where tokenId=token1 // token1 is from the prev query.
```

How can i pass the value from 1st query to the second ?

```
Ive tried : 

declare @tmp int

Select name, age ,@tmp=token1 from Mytable where id=2
```

but its not working...

Comment: Does the first query only return at most one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix a `select` that assigns to variables with one that returns results. If the first query only returns at most one row you can use

```
SELECT @name = name,
       @age = age,
       @token1 = token1
FROM   Mytable
WHERE  id = 2

IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 1)
    RAISERROR('Multiple rows returned - Indeterminate result',16,1)

/*Return result to client*/
SELECT @name   AS name,
       @age    AS age,
       @token1 AS token1

SELECT anotherCalc
FROM   Table2
WHERE  tokenId = @token1
```

Comment: if my query has many columns  , Should i open a variable for each  one ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yes. Or insert the single row into a table variable and use that instead.

Comment: what you mean is that the long Calculated row result - should be insetted to #tmp  - and then i can read it from evberywhere in the scope ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - could be, not should be necessarily but might be a bit neater than declaring a load of scalar variables. Also for a single row I would use a `@table_var` not a `#temp` table probably.